# How to Use LLIST *mylist[N];

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I get this:

```
LLIST *mylist[N];
```

Where N is the number of rows of the input file. Then `mylist[i]` is a pointer to the ith linked list.

I call a function

```
LLIST *list_add(LLIST **p, int i){
    LLIST *n;

    n = (LLIST *) malloc(sizeof(LLIST));

    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;

    n->next = *p; /* the previous element (*p) now becomes the "next" element */
    *p = n;       /* add new empty element to the front (head) of the list */
    n->data = i;
    return p;
}
```

So in my Main I say something like

```
LLIST *mylist[N];
list_add(&mylist[0],1);
list_add(&mylist[0],2);
list_add(&mylist[1],3)
list_add(&mylist[1],4);
list_print(mylist[0]); // Print mylist[0]
list_print(mylist[1]); // Print mylist[1]
```

My Print_list function is:

```
Void *list_print(LLIST *n) {
    if (n == NULL){ 
        printf("list is empty\n");
    }

    while (n != NULL){
        printf("%d",n->data); 
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

When I do `list_print(mylist[0])`, it prints out `2 1`.

When I do `list_print(mylist[1])`, I get a segmentation fault.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you perhaps, in the same class as jmh86: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106691/c-issue-cant-figure-how-to-assign-pointer-to-beginning-of-list ? Or maybe not. You question and first line ask about `INTLIST`, but the rest of the code uses `LLIST`, and you haven't shown us how either one is built. More specifics, please.

Comment: Also, it is always worth running with the debugger to see what line it seg faults on. (Use `-g` when compiling and linking with gcc, and `gdb programname` in a unix like environment.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion between.. It is suppose to be LLIST, not INTLIST.

Comment: Finally, it is usual to tag homework as such, not because there is anything wrong with homework questions, but because it helps us guess what kind of help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to initialize the contents of the `mylist` array, and it might contain values that point at random memory locations. When just adding new elements this doesn't matter, new elements are inserted at the beginning, never accessing the invalid pointers. But when you try to print the list, the print function will follow the invalid pointer at the end of the list and produce a segmentation fault.

To avoid this add an initializer to the array declaration:

```
LLIST *mylist[N] = {NULL};
```

This will set all elements of `mylist` to `NULL`.

Comment: Best guess with what we're been given, except that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106691/c-issue-cant-figure-how-to-assign-pointer-to-beginning-of-list there seems to be a special initializing function for the first node.

Comment: Well I have it initialized as LLIST mylist*[2]; 

Every Time I run this I get different results. 

It is now printing *mylist[1]; 
but when i print mylist[0]; it prints 2 1 1 (repeated 1);

Comment: LLIST *mylist[N] = {NULL}; fixed the issue I guess.. I need to do more testing. I'm not confident though.

Comment: @MRP: `LLIST *mylist[2]` *decalares* mylist to be a *uninitialized* two element array of `LLIST*`s. But at that point the values of `mylist[0]` and `mylist[1]` could be *anything*. Accessing them at that point (without setting) to something known invokes undefined behavior. You are at risk of nasal demons.

Comment: Well I have tested it using this code and it does print out the correctly:

int main(void)
{
int i,j;
LLIST *mylist[10] = {NULL};


for(i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
 
 for(j=0; j<10; j++)
 {
    list_add(&mylist[i],j);

 }
}

for(i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
  list_print(mylist[i]);
}
}

I am a newbie at C programming but I understand concepts of programing... I dont know if I'm still at risk with the given code.

Comment: So pretty much i get a print out like this...

9876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210

Comment: The test works, but am I still at risk?
btw, Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This does work
LLIST *mylist[10] = {NULL};

But would if I wanted to do this I get errors:
x=10;
LLIST *mylist[x] = {NULL};

Answer (score 0):

This does work LLIST *mylist[10] = {NULL}; 
But would if I wanted to do this I get errors:

x=10;
 LLIST *mylist[x] = {NULL};